# Abrir ventana nueva de chrome desde firefox/internet explorer

Tags: javascript

mi consulta es como puedo abrir una nueva ventana de google chrome desde firefox o internet explorer usando javascript, todos los ejemplos que he podido ver son para abrir ventanas sobre el mismo navegador en que te encuentras, pero sera posible abrir una ventana de un navegador diferente?

Saldos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible por cuestiones seguridad. Sino podria crearse un caos.
Con mas detalle ya han respondido en foro en ingles: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235353/opening-one-browser-from-another-browser)